# Error when opening .tar.gz via Shell to install Apache Maven

Tags: shell, maven, jung, unpack, gzip

**Machine:**

Mac OSX 10.5.8 32-bit.

---

**Goal:**

To install apache maven per its [websites instructions](http://maven.apache.org/download.html), in order to install the JUNG package according to its [install instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNGManual), so I can use the JUNG classes in various Java GUIs.

---

**What I Did:**

Downloaded a .tar.gz file, and using the shell, moved it to a directory (using *mv*) I created for it (using *mkdir*), *usr/local/apache-maven* per the website directions
I downloaded the file *apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz*. Next I tried extracting the file using *tar -zxvf apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz*.

---

**Error:**

I get an error message when I try to extract the apache-maven .gz (install?) file in shell.

```
tar: apache-maven-3.0.4/direcoryandfile: Cannot open: No such file or directory
... 
apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/ext: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/ext/README.txt 
tar: apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/ext/README.txt: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar:       
Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

---

**Instructions:**

For the maven building

> 1. Extract the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4... The subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive. 
>      ...

for the JUNG installation

> Appendix: How to Build JUNG
>
> Get Maven
>
> Download and install maven2 from maven.apache.org: http://maven.apache.org/download.html. At time of writing (early June 2012), the latest version was maven-3.0.4. Install the downloaded maven2 (there are installation instructions on the Maven website).
>
> Follow the installation instructions and confirm a successful installation by typing 'mvn --version' in a command terminal window.

---

**Self-Rectification Attempts**

From what I can tell the archive file is missing some directories or something. I tried deleting the file, redownloading the .tar.gz file from a different mirror and repeating the process. Same result. Thanks again for the help

---

**Background:**

I'm trying to install the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html) package to my system's Java, so I can write object-oriented code using various GUIs (Ecliplse, Dr. Java) using the classes in JUNG. I don't understand how the building/installing process works, and how I can get what I build/install to work on various GUIs and the command line. I'm new to shell and the command line, and mostly have experience using a simple IDE (DrJava, Python IDLE, R GUI) to write and compile object-oriented code.

Comment: run chmod -R 777 apache-maven-2.2.1.tar.gz, then run tar -xf apache-maven-2.2.1.tar

Comment: Kltis, I tried your solution, and I had the same problem as listedbelow in teh answer to khmarbaise's response. Thanks though!

Comment: The installation instructions were out of date; I've updated them (thanks for the heads-up).  You should be able to use the latest version of Maven.  Please follow Maven's instructions for downloading and using it.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Edited the question to reflect this change

Comment: Josh; the following website, which also has instructions for installation, also lists the latest apache as version 2: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/BuildingJUNG2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Two Step Process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588491/1077083):
1. Extract the *.tar* from the *.tar.gz* using *gunzip*, and *-v* for having *gunzip* print what its doing. `gunzip -v apache-maven-3.0.4.tar.gz`
2. Extract the *.tar* file using *tar*, *-x* for telling the program to do an extraction, *-v* for having *tar* print what its doing, and *-f* for *tar* to know that the following file is the archive and appending with *sudo* so *tar* has permission to create directories. `sudo tar -xvf apache-maven-3.0.4.tar`

Answer (score 2):

To unpack a tar.gz archive you need to do it either in two steps:

```
gunzip apache-maven-3.0.4.tar.gz 
tar -xf apache-maven-3.0.4.tar
```

or you might try to do it in a single step:

```
tar -zxf apache-maven-3.0.4.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Your suggestion was partially successful... I ran gunzip on the .tar.gz file, which seemed to work; when I did 'ls' it listed the same file name but without a _.gz_, i.e. 'apache-maven-2.2.1.tar'. When I tried doing 'tar -xf apache-maven-2.2.1.tar' I got the following error message, similar to the message I got before 'tar: apache-maven-2.2.1/directoryandorfile:  Cannot open: No such file or directory... tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors'. It seems I'm having a similar error. Any idea why? Also, JUNG website specified use maven 2, as per my post

Comment: Have you tried tar -tvvf apache-maven-2.2.1.tar ?Error message?

Comment: BTW: On what OS are you trying to unpack the tar file ?