# Extracting .tar file isn't working

Tags: shell, maven, extract, tar

Thanks ahead of time for all your help guys! As a beginner user I really appreciate the help!

---

**My Machine/OS:**
Mac OSX 10.5.8, 32-bit

---

**What I'm trying to do:**
Extract and install Apache Maven, from the [website](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).

---

**What I've done:**
Downloaded the binary *.tar.gz* file from the website, and using the shell, moved the downloaded file to the appropariate directory, and extracted the *.tar* out of the *.tar.gz* by using `gunzip -v filename.tar.gz`, resulting a *.tar* file. Now I'm trying to extract the *.tar* file using `tar -xv filename.tar`.

---

**My Problem**
The extraction doesn't seem to be working! After I've typed the `tar -xv filename.tar` command and hit enter, the shell isn't returning any output, and doesn't seem to complete the extraction. It stays indefinitely with the empty line returned after hitting enter.

---

**My Attempts**
Examining the directory from another Shell window, both while `tar` is running and after quitting the shell while the process is running, doesn't show any changes in the files contained; i.e. the only file/directory present is the original *.tar.gz* file. I've also tried deleting the file along with the directory containing it, re-creating the directory, re-copying the file into the directory, and then re-trying the `tar -xv filename.tar` command. The result is the same

---

Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: The way to indicate that a question has been answered is to accept one of the answers by clicking the checkmark icon. (It looks like Eduardo's answer is the one that solved the problem, but that's up to you to determine.) Or you can post an answer yourself. Including the answer in the question just causes confusion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try the following command:

```
tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
```

Comment: Eduardo, thank you for the suggestion, I answered my question per the comment below. Thanks again!

Comment: Careful with **absolute paths**. If you specified an absolute path when creating your tar, then when you unzip it, it will be **contained** within that same folder path, **not** the original folder name. This once got me thinking the extract wasn't working.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo tar -xvf filename.tar`

This fixes two problems with the above `tar -xv filename.tar`.

1st Issue: Needed to include a the *-f* modifier for *tar*. Per [lowfatlinux][2], *-f* is a command for *tar* that says:

"The archive file name is given on the command line (required whenever the tar output is going to a file)"

Therefore, including the *-f* modifier tells the *tar* program that the file name supplied in the arguments is the file to extract from.

2nd Issue: Needed to append *sudo* to the beginning of the command, to give the shell permission to create directories

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
gunzip -c filename.tar.gz | tar xopf -
```

After you tried gunzip, use tar xopf on that file

```
tar xopf filename.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your download was most likely corrupted, notice what it says on the website:

> NOTE Following links will list to you various available mirrors. DO NOT USE those links directly.

This mirror worked for me on Debian:

> wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz
>   tar -xvzf apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz

Comment: Shahin, Thank you for the help. I downloaded the file off of a mirror as the site recommended; I answered my question above. Thank you again.